# What's my "homing attack"?

Tags: lollipop-chainsaw

A couple of loading screens or something referred to a "homing attack" then my sister called and yelled at me to use this same attack. I don't really know what they mean. I just got the Chainsaw Blaster but I wouldn't really call it "homing". I see no reference to this in the "How to cook zombie" manual. Is this just a weird way of saying "Lock on" or what?

How do I do a homing attack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "homing attack" is simply the Pom-Pom attack (<kbd>Square</kbd> on PS3, I assume <kbd>X</kbd> on 360), it homes in on nearby enemies and upgrading the Pom-Poms will increase the homing range. It just helps to keep the combos going.

Comment: Oh, so it is; a bit after posting this I got the first homing upgrade which actually explains it too.